# How make, what would the two web project in one solution work under one instance? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have one web project on VB.NET and created second web project on C#. I want that my site work as a single whole. Example go to url http://mysite.com/default.aspx - page from first web project, but if i go to http://mysite.com/manage/default.aspx - this page from second web project. Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work without any problems.

There are two ways I can think of to do this, simply putting the second project in a folder within the first should work (Although you will need to move the DLLs from the second projects bin directory into the first one.

so:

```
Web Site Root
 L Project 1 <Directory>
  L Bin <Directory>
   L Project1.DLL
   L Project2.DLL
  L Default.aspx
 L Project 2 <Directory>
  L Default.aspx
```

The other way would be to create a virtual directory/Application pointing at the second project from within the first (Though the bin directory thing will still apply for the virtual directory solution)

Once its compiled its not c# or VB anymore, it gets compiled into IL so it shoudnt matter what language you originally used as long as it compiles down into IL.